# Sharing JWT token between backend (.Net) and frontent (angular)

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, architecture, jwt, authorization

I have a specific project where I use .Net ASP MVC application with frontent build with Angular 7.
By "specific" i mean that angular has routing disabled - routing is handled by MVC backend application. It returns cshtml view (with some data passed to script tag) and angular renders its view.

Now the case is I want to include authorization with JWT token and have a problem with the architecture.

1. MVC handles routing, so it should "know" the token i.e. to autorize requests, etc.
2. Angular can process business logic via API using access token
3. If angular gather a token (passing user name/password) backend can not generate its own access_token, because it does not know the credentials. And it could lead to desynchronization of data betweek front/back-end
4. Only one app should handle refresh token

So which application should handle the process of gathering access_token from AuthServer?
What should be responsible for refreshing token?
Where to store the token?

Can anyone show me the starting point?

Comment: The authentication is handled by a SSO or by your backend?

Comment: If I understand You correctly - Token is generated by a separate AuthAPI that I also created myself (based on whole oauth & identity middleware).

Answer (score 0):

In general, using a client-side Angular application to obtain an `access_token` is a dangerous solution. When an access token is created via Javascript, it is subject to a number of attacks including XSS and XSRF.

The current best practice approach is to send the user's credentials securely to your server-side application and allow it to handle the authentication and authorization flow. Alternatively, delegate to a third-party product designed for this scenario. When your user first attempts to access a protected client-side view, it should perform a server-side request for secure data. A session should be created for the user on your server-side application, during which they should be prompted for authentication. When authentication is complete, your server application can choose to share (and store) the JWT with the client application via a httpOnly and Secure cookie.

Using a httpOnly and Secure cookie ensures that the token is not shared with anyone other than the user's browser.